# multiple karate.call in karate.config.js with different var names to same feature file

Tags: karate

I am trying to test role specific features in parallel in karate. I have few features for each role and needs role specific token for auth.

I am trying to call a token generation url for various roles and store the token in karate.config.js in different variable names to re-use across the respective scenarios without having to call the token generration once per feature.

var adminTokenResponse = karate.call('classpath:helpers/GenerateToken.feature',{username: 'jane', password: 'somesecret'})
config.adminToken = adminTokenResponse.token

var userTokenResponse = karate.call('classpath:helpers/GenerateToken.feature',{username: 'john', password: 'nothingsecret'})
config.userToken = userTokenResponse.token

var superAdminResponse = karate.call('classpath:helpers/GenerateToken.feature',{username: 'king', password: 'topsecret'})
config.superAdminToken = superAdminResponse.token

Expectation:
Karate calls the Generate token three times and sets appropriate tokens.

Actual:
Karate calls the Generate token only once and sets admin token to all the three variables.

I used a work around by adding three feature files as below and called the GenerateToken within them and it worked. Is there a way we can generate different tokens without having to create additional features. If there are 10 roles I have to create 10 features to get those tokens.

var adminTokenResponse = karate.call('classpath:helpers/GenerateAdminToken.feature',{username: 'jane', password: 'somesecret'})
config.adminToken = adminTokenResponse.token

var userTokenResponse = karate.call('classpath:helpers/GenerateUserToken.feature',{username: 'john', password: 'nothingsecret'})
config.userToken = userTokenResponse.token

var superAdminResponse = karate.call('classpath:helpers/GenerateSuperAdminToken.feature',{username: 'king', password: 'topsecret'})
config.superAdminToken = superAdminResponse.token

Comment: this is not supposed to happen, so my suggestion is you submit a way to replicate following this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue